# Web API Extended Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application that has implemented the latest Web API as a restful server for a mostly javascript/ajax based web application built on .NET 4.5.  I'm using forms authentication and its working as it should to secure the web api as well as the rest of the application.

I'm wanting to add another layer of security to the Web API to prevent users from using another user guid in a manual request to the API.  They would have to view the source in another logged in user's browser to get that user's guid from a hidden input.  They could then potentially use that guid to access the other user's data through their own authenticated session.  Of course this bad person would have to be authenticated under their own account for this to work.

What I'm thinking of doing is passing the user guid with every api request and if that guid matches HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name then allow the request...otherwise throw an unauthorized exception and handle it on the client accordingly.  But then all of my handler methods become a bit dirty as shown below...this would have to be in each and every GET, POST, PUT, etc... along with other objects in most cases.

```
public Community Get(string userGuid)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == userGuid)
            return myDataHandler.getUserData();
        else
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

I can make this work but it seems like a bit too much overhead.  I've looked at numerous posts and articles regarding web api security but nothing regarding this potential situation.  What is the best way to verify every request is actually requesting information regarding the user logged in without having to do what I'm doing above?  Possibly use this idea but do it globally for each api request instead of it being tested in every method?  Another way around this is to user HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name for every request instead of relying on what is sent from the client...but I'm not sure this will work in all of my situations...as my application is still young.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently putting together an API which uses bearer authentication (See Microsoft documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) as there is too much detail to post here).

One thing I am using are Claims, and one of the claims I am setting is a User ID which forms part of a User Identity. When someone authenticates with the API the claims are also set (read from the token) and can be accessed from the User Context as you are currently doing to access the name.

By doing it that way you don't need to store the Guid in a hidden field.